# Не получается получить доступ к динамически загруженному элементу

Tags: jquery

```js
    $('.ml-1.mode_checkbox_post').on("click", function() {
        var mode = $('.ml-1.mode_checkbox_post').attr('data-mode');

        if (mode == 'off') {
            $(this).attr('data-mode','on');
            $(this).html('<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i> Только друзьям');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('data-mode','off');
            $(this).html('<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i> Для всех');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ml-1 mode_checkbox_post" data-mode="off">
    <i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i> Для всех
 </a>
```

Использую **on()** для работы с динамически загруженными данными, но не получается получить доступ. В консоле ничего не отображается.

Comment: `on` - это просто добавление обработчика события. Поэтому если код `$('.ml-1.mode_checkbox_post').on` исполняется до добавления элементов, то толку от него нет. Для делегирования события нужно вешать обработчик на статичного родителя (лучше на ближайшего, но в крайнем случае - на `body` или `document`). Выглядит это примерно так: `$(document).on("click", '.ml-1.mode_checkbox_post', ...`

Comment: А как должно быть? В текущем виде код работает как написан.

Comment: В текущем виде работает, а если объект загружен динамически - нет

Comment: @Regent, добавь ответ, чтобы я его отметил. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on` - это просто добавление обработчика события. Поэтому если код `$('.ml-1.mode_checkbox_post').on(...` исполняется до добавления элементов, то толку от него нет.

Для делегирования события нужно вешать обработчик на статичного родителя (лучше на ближайшего, но в крайнем случае - на `"body"` или `document`). Выглядит это примерно так:

```
$(document).on("click", '.ml-1.mode_checkbox_post', ...
```